# raspberry pi ultrasonic in MATLAB Simulink (UAV Obstacle detection)

Tags: matlab, simulink, raspberry-pi2

I'm currently working in Simulink with the hardware support package for raspberrypi. At the moment I'm trying to get depth data from the HCSR04 ultrasonic sonar sensor connected to the raspberrypi as shown below:

[image: simulink model]

I'm following [*this video*](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=i4zwhtYzIIk&feature=youtu.be) for all the parameters and yet cannot get in data at the output. I can't understand why it doesn't work. What does it not work?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to follow a step by step procedure to isolate the real issue.

```
   1.Make sure that GPIO blocks are working fine.
   2.Connect GPIO17 & GPIO4 together (loopback connection)
   3.Run your model in "External mode".
   4.You should be able to view the pulses via scope.
```

The above steps will make sure that Raspberry Pi is configured properly to work with Simulink and GPIO blocks are working properly.

Once you are confident with GPIO blocks, connect the ultrasonic sensor and try to get data.